# pyqt : dock on side of stacked qdockwidgets

Tags: pyqt, qdockwidget

[image: multi dock]

I've made a multi-docks window. To do that, I hide central widget, and I got it. But I have a problem (or more things maybe?). If the dock widgets are stacked on top of another, I can't dock the one the side of them. As seen with above figure, I just have to dock between docks. How can I adjust it? That's the whole code of mine.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)        
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "self", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.setDockOptions(QtGui.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.hide()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)        
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.dock1Widget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock1Widget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.AllDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.dock1Widget.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "dock1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dock1WidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dock1Widget.setWidget(self.dock1WidgetContents)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dock1Widget)
        self.dock2Widget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock2Widget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.AllDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.dock2Widget.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "dock2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dock2WidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dock2Widget.setWidget(self.dock2WidgetContents)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dock2Widget)
        self.dock3Widget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock3Widget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.AllDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.dock3Widget.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "dock3", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dock3WidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dock3Widget.setWidget(self.dock3WidgetContents)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dock3Widget)
        self.dock4Widget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self)
        self.dock4Widget.setFeatures(QtGui.QDockWidget.AllDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.dock4Widget.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "dock4", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.dock4WidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dock4Widget.setWidget(self.dock4WidgetContents)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), self.dock4Widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a `centralWidget` a single `dockWidgetArea` can expand all the way and make all other dock areas unaccessible.

One possible solution is using nested docks ([`AllowNestedDocks`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#DockOption-enum)). This will allow you to stack dock widgets more freely. It's not exactly the same behavior but maybe more flexible. Set your docking options like this:

```
self.setDockOptions(QtGui.QMainWindow.AnimatedDocks | QtGui.QMainWindow.AllowNestedDocks)
```

By the way, if you don't want a central widget, you can just *not set* it. Default value is `NULL` and this has the same effect of setting a dummy widget and hiding.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. As you recommended, I rewrote the my code :)